# add active class to li from page url

Tags: php, css, class, url

I am using the following to get the active page url:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

echoing the above gives me my URL as follows:

```
http://www.domain-nane.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6&Itemid=109
```

I want to add a class of 'current' to my 'li' if the active page is present - dependant on the 'Itemid' contained in the url - i.e.

```
<li class="current">
   <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=109">Link 1</a>
<li>
   <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=110">Link 2</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=111">Link 3</a>
</li>
```

Any hints/ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "_the page is present_"? do you mean if it is the page being currently displayed?

Comment: I think that he say current page...

Comment: yes... if the current page being displayed matches the <a href...>  Itemid (at the end of the url), then I want to apply the class="current to my 'li'

Comment: but Joomla! does it automatically

Comment: Yes... I know - but this is a strange module I'm trying to hack :(

Comment: I recommend you to use mod_rewrite... your url is very bad

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want something like this:

```
 <ul id="navigation">
    <li <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>><a href="index.php">Home Page</a></li>
    <li <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'about.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>><a href="about.php">About Me</a></li>
    <li <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'contact.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>><a href="contact.php">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'portfolio.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>><a href="portfolio.php">My Work</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I hope this will help you!

PS: index.php, about.php, contact.php and portofolio.php must be replaced with your pages links.

Comment: Don't think you quite understood the question - I need to add the class to the 'li', not the link

Answer (score 2):

you are doing wrong thing

simple way is below..

In your URL `Itemid` is unique, so its better to do this in following way

```
<li <?php if($Itemid == $_REQUEST['Itemid']) { echo class='current'; } ?> >
   <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=109">Link 1</a>
</li>

<li <?php if($Itemid == $_REQUEST['Itemid']) { echo class='current'; } ?> >
   <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=110">Link 2</a>
</li>

<li <?php if($Itemid == $_REQUEST['Itemid']) { echo class='current'; } ?> >
   <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=111">Link 3</a>
</li>
```

Comment: he can store Itemid in variable, its simple... thats why i have added variable `$Itemid`, he can compare itemid and generate output of current li

Comment: Yes, he can put in the menu other external links, categories etc. I think it must get the id of button, and after the id active page (check this tutorial, for current itemID http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_Page_Class_Suffix_in_Template_Code )

Answer (score 0):

its simple

```
<li class="<?php if($Itemid == $_REQUEST['Itemid']) { echo 'active'; } ?> ">
```

This will look like this is in HTML

```
<li class="active">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want solution in Javascript.
Here my suggestion
Your Html code

```
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li class="current">
      <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=109">Link 1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=110">Link 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=111">Link 3</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Javascript Code

```
url = 'http://www.domain-nane.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6&Itemid=111';
   //  url = '<php echo curPageURL();?>';
var urlRegex =/Itemid=([0-9]+)/i;
var Itemid = url.match(urlRegex)[1];
// alert(Itemid);

var nodes = document.getElementById('navigation').childNodes;
var lis;
for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    if(nodes[i].nodeType == 1){
      var lis = nodes[i];
      var aElem =   lis.childNodes[1];
      var AItemId = aElem.href.match(urlRegex)[1];
    if(Itemid == AItemId) {
        lis.className = lis.className + " current";
    }
    }
}
```

Running Example
http://jsfiddle.net/xdsUm/3/