# php if condition: check if the page href is identical

Tags: php

What is the if condition for php to check if the page the user is viewing is identical as URL?

For example, here is a default URL: `"example.com/my_name"`

If the user is viewing "`example.com/my_name"`, then the condition is met.

However, if the user is viewing `"example.com/my_name&first_name"` then the condition is not met.

(I am not sure if I am explaining it right :P)

Thanks!

Comment: i think you mean to say URL rather than `href`. `href` is just an anchor attribute.

Comment: look into this: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`; source: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: oops. I meant URL. :P thanks!

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467614/add-active-class-to-li-from-page-url

Comment: I see something like this `"if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php'))"` from the question link you provided. If I want to check a specific url (like "example.com/my_name"), then would the following be correct ?  `if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI], 'http://example.com/my_name'))`

Comment: And automatically the questions jump into my mind, is `"example.com/my_dir/"` the same as `"example.com/my_dir/index.php"`? Or the same as `"EXAMPLE.COM/my_dir/"`? Or `"example.com\\my_dir\\"` etc. Sometimes I hate myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to use the [SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables, i.e.:

```
$currentLocation = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$base = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/my_name";


if($currentLocation != $base){
    echo "LOCATION DENIED";
}else{
    echo "LOCATION OK";
}
```

The above code compares the base location with the current user location;

---

```
'SERVER_NAME'
```

> The name of the server host under which the current script is
>   executing. If the script is running on a virtual host, this will be
>   the value defined for that virtual host.

```
'REQUEST_URI'
```

> The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance,
>   '/index.html'.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: This is brilliant! =) Thank you. Learned something new! =)